# Need help to setup two column layout in HTML

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to set up a two column layout in HTML. I am facing problem when the content of the first column grows more than one line. In that case the div which should come below this one is moved to next column because space is available there. here is the link and code for more clarity
http://jsfiddle.net/9xp1sj05/1/

```
<div style="width:47.5%; float:left; display:inline-block">this is column1 with
    <br>a break tag to show it has
    <br>bigger hieght</div>
<div style="width:47.5%; display:inline-block">this is column2</div>
<div style="width:47.5%; float:left; display:inline-block">row2:column1 should come below column1</div>
```

I can give line-height to column2, but in my case I have to setup the column layout before the actual content in the divs are loaded. So I dont know exactly how much height would column1 take. Is there any way by which I can declare that only one div should come after column1??

Please note that this is just an example, in the real use case, there are more than 10 rows which are loaded dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make an abstract image of what your desired layout looks like as it is totally unclear.

Comment: you want second div under the first div? then simply dnt use inline property or if m wrong then let me know more about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` and give `vertical-align: top;` to each div will solved your issue.

```
style="width:47.5%; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;"
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9xp1sj05/3/)

Comment: thanks a lot it works great for me :)
just wanted to know is there a way by which I can put content of column2 in vertical middle with respect to column1? I am trying to avoid line-height because I cant give a specific number

Answer (score 0):

Just add `clear:left` to the css of the 3rd div:

```
<div style="width:47.5%; float:left; clear:left; display:inline-block">row2:column1 should come below column1</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9xp1sj05/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div style="width:47.5%; float:left;">this is column1
<br>this is column1
    <br>this is column1
        <br>this is column1
</div>
<div style="width:47.5%; float:left; ">this is column2</div>
<div style="width:47.5%; float:left; clear:both;">row2:column1 should come below column1</div>
```